# pythonとopencvを使って角度付き矩形中の指定した位置に直線を描画したい

Tags: python, python3, opencv

### 概要

角度付き矩形の中に、矩形の長辺と同じ長さの直線を描画する方法を教えてください
言語はPythonで描画に使用するライブラリはOpenCVです
バージョンはそれぞれ下記のとおりです
Python: 3.7.9
OpenCV: 4.6.0

### 詳細

直線をより詳細に説明すると、矩形の短辺から相対する短辺まで下した垂線です
使用できる情報は以下の通りです

1. 矩形の中心座標
2. 回転前の矩形の左上座標
3. 矩形の回転角度
4. 矩形のサイズ
5. 矩形の長編の一方を0とした時の直線までの距離

これら5つの情報を使って添付した画像の赤色直線を描画したいです
4の直線までの距離というのは、添付した画像の緑色直線の長さを示しております
[image: 描画したい矩形のイメージ図]

回転角度付きの矩形を描画する方法は[回転角度付き矩形の描画方法](https://aihints.com/how-to-draw-rotated-rectangle-in-opencv-python/)のサイトを参考にしました
実際に記述したコードは次の通りです

```
def draw_rotate_rect(img, rect, color):
    #rectには回転前の矩形の左上座標が含まれている
    center_x = rect[0] + rect[2] // 2
    center_y = rect[1] + rect[3] // 2
    w, h, ang = rect[2], rect[3], -rect[4]

    rot_rect = ((center_x, center_y), (w, h), ang)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rot_rect)
    box = np.int0(box)

    img = cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, color, 1)
```

Comment: 準備や使い方を推測して補完しなくても試せる完結したソースコードを提示してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`boxPoints`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf78d467e024b4d7936cf9397185d2f5c)で回転後の座標を求めていますので、それと同様に緑線の長さの分だけ**両端が短い矩形**の座標を求めれば描画可能です。

**サンプルコード**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# 引数`len`は緑色直線の長さ相当の整数
def draw_rotate_rect(img, rect, color, len):
    #rectには回転前の矩形の左上座標が含まれている
    center_x = rect[0] + rect[2] // 2
    center_y = rect[1] + rect[3] // 2
    w, h, ang = rect[2], rect[3], -rect[4]

    rot_rect = ((center_x, center_y), (w, h), ang)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rot_rect)
    box = np.int0(box)

    img = cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, color, 1)

    # 幅がlen*2(緑色の線)の分だけ狭い枠線を回転させて座標を求める
    rect2 = ((center_x, center_y), (rect[2] - len*2, rect[3]), ang)
    b2 = cv2.boxPoints(rect2)
    pt1_1 = (int(b2[0][0]), int(b2[0][1])) # 左下
    pt1_2 = (int(b2[1][0]), int(b2[1][1])) # 左上
    img = cv2.line(img, pt1_1, pt1_2, (0, 0, 255), 1) # 赤線
    pt2_1 = (int(b2[2][0]), int(b2[2][1])) # 右上
    pt2_2 = (int(b2[3][0]), int(b2[3][1])) # 右下
    img = cv2.line(img, pt2_1, pt2_2, (0, 255, 0), 1) # 緑線

    # 高さがlen*2(緑色の線)の分だけ狭い以下略
    rect3 = ((center_x, center_y), (rect[2], rect[3] - len*2), ang)
    b3 = cv2.boxPoints(rect3)
    pt3_1 = (int(b3[0][0]), int(b3[0][1])) # 左下
    pt3_2 = (int(b3[3][0]), int(b3[3][1])) # 右下
    img = cv2.line(img, pt3_1, pt3_2, (255, 0, 0), 1) # 青線
    pt4_2 = (int(b3[1][0]), int(b3[1][1])) # 左上
    pt4_1 = (int(b3[2][0]), int(b3[2][1])) # 右上
    img = cv2.line(img, pt4_1, pt4_2, (200, 200, 0), 1) # 水色線

img = np.zeros((480,640,3), np.uint8)
draw_rotate_rect(img, (100, 100, 100, 300, 10), (255, 255, 255), 20)
cv2.imwrite("test.png", img)
```

**実行結果**

[image: 実行結果]

Answer (score 0):

> 角度付き矩形の中に、矩形の長辺と同じ長さの直線を描画する

ということで，「角度付き矩形」も描画対象なのであり，その目的で質問内提示コードの処理 `box = cv2.boxPoints(rot_rect)` が行われている，
という前提の上で考えるとすれば，
この時点で矩形の４頂点の座標が得られている，すなわち各辺の両端点の座標があるのですから，辺上の点の座標は単純に，比率なりから求めればよいだけでしょう．